# Can I have the same mapping value with different param in a different Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any way to accomplish something like this:
I have a form used for navigation :

```
<form action="mapping.do">

   <input type="submit" value="menuOption01" />

   <input type="submit" value="menuOption02" />

</form>
```

The `PageController` class is too big and has too many dependancies, I need to add another menu option but don't want to add to the complexity. I'd like to have a method in another controller which handles the new menu option.

Trying this gives me a Spring configutation error (There is already handler mapped):

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = { Entity.class })
class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "menuOption01", value = "mapping.do")
    public String viewPage(@ModelAttribute final Entity entity) {
        ...
        return "view";
    }

    ... // another 5000 lines of code

}


@Controller
class OtherController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "menuOption02", value = "mapping.do")
    public String viewOtherPage(@ModelAttribute final Entity entity) {
        ...
        return "otherview";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar situation so we made the following default handler for these types of methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = SIDE_TAB, value = "sideMenuController.xhtml")
public ModelAndView changeSelectedTab(@RequestParam(SIDE_TAB) String sideTab) {
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/location/" + Utils.toCamelCase(sideTab) + ".xhtml");
}
```

Our pages then had the following:

```
<input type='submit' name='side-tab' value='$value' />
```

This of course meant that we had to have a naming standard for the files themselves, but that was quite easy to ensure happened (i.e. "Event History" would go to eventHistory.xhtml, "Create New Entity" would go to "createNewEntity.xhtml", etc....)

Comment: Obviously $value needs to be replaced for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but:

- You can include that param in the url: `value=/mapping/parameter/` and `/mapping/otherparameter`. (The `.do` extension is a bit obsolete btw)
- Use an `if` clause - pass the two params with `@RequestParam("param", required=false) String param` and use `if (param != null) viewPage();`
- You can have one method that takes `HttpServletRequest` and checks whether a parameter with a given name exists (using `request.getParameter("foo") != null`)

Comment: Thanks, a couple of things ... Spring 2.4 & I can't change the mapping value. I'm trying to avoid adding more methods to an already large controller.

Comment: I don't understand the second option - my problem at the minute is that spring complains of two mapping values in separate controllers ... my underlying problem is a badly designed menu system which uses params and a form to map to different views.

Comment: well, that's not that bad - you can have 1 method that takes a HttpServletRequest and check for each parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter per method mapping. See my question and answer:

- @RequestMapping with "params" on same URL in different classes cause "IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler" in JUnit with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563228/173149

Just use these classes:

```
  <bean name="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
  <bean name="handlerAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>
```